# How to remove unwanted properties from object while making Put Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the asp.net application integrated with the Shopify e-commerce store. I have a Variant class that contains some properties like below:

```
public class Variant{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is with Quantity property. When making a Post request, it allows to define quantity, but when making a Put request, it won't allow sending this Quantity property in the object.

I want to ignore this Quantity property while making a Put request

Comment: Its simple, create two DTO, one for put and one for post

Comment: You can either use two DTO or make Quantity nullable (int?)

Comment: @akseli Nullable properties are ignored when not defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can put the below line in the property you want to ignore when null but this is if you serialize that with Json.NET.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Check out this great [article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx)